# Verbose mode of Git pull from origin

Tags: git

Is there a way to show all commits like a "verbose" or "debug" function when using `git pull origin master`?

I just want to see what changes are committed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `git log` a lot.

Try this out:

```
git log --graph --all --decorate
```

Gives a great overview.

Comment: And if you are using Windows or MacOSX I'll recommend you to test sourcetree. Best gui I've tried so far.

Comment: I personally enjoy `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --branches=*` as it makes a very readable but rich graph.

Comment: @srt32 In `--branches=*` I needed to add quotes, i.e: `--branches='*'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `git fetch origin master` followed by `log`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use **git log -p** . Here is more detail [Git Viewing the Commit History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).
If you are using Max OS X, I suggest to use [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

On the same branch.

```
git checkout master
git status
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
git diff origin/master
```

You should see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyway of showing each commit as part of the `git pull` operation, but the original HEAD is stored as `ORIG_HEAD` by `git pull`.  So you can do something like this--after `git pull`--to see what's new:

```
git log --all --not ORIG_HEAD
```

The [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) has a similar alias in the `alias.*` section, but using `gitk` instead:

```
gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD
```

You can create an alias `new` like this:

```
git config --global alias.new 'log --all --not ORIG_HEAD'
```

Or, using `gitk`:

```
git config --global alias.new '!gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a lot : git log --pretty=oneline

And I'm using these aliases in my file .gitconfig

```
[color]
    ui = true

[alias]

##### Log aliases
# Show HEAD commit
head = log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative -n1
# Short one line logs with ref-names
l  = log --oneline --decorate=short
# Shows the last git logentry (hash, author, date commitmessage)
llm = log -1
# Short one line logs with ref-names and statistics
gl = log --oneline --decorate --stat --graph
# Short one line logs with ref-names (yellow, date (green) and author (blue)
glog = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
# Show last commit
lc = log ORIG_HEAD.. --stat --no-merges
# Graph log with full commit message
glaaa = log --graph --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull --rebase -v
```

-v stands for verbose